# Get Parameter from an object in a list

Tags: java, closures

Is there a nice way in Java to read a parameter from an object in a list? For example I often want to get all ids in my objects that are part of a list. The code I usually write for this is as below.

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (MyObject myObj : myObjs){
    ids.add(myObj.getId());
}
```

Is there any other way of doing this or any other pattern? Or am I just waiting for (proper) closures to appear in java. All I want is a one-line to return a list of all the values of one parameter of a list.

Thanks

Comment: If you do it often, you can make a utility method for this.

Comment: Try [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava [`Lists.transform`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html):

```
final List<Integer> ids = Lists.transform(myObjs, new Function<MyObject, Long>() {
    public Long apply(final MyObject input) {
        return input.getId();
    }
});
```

EDIT: you can also use a custom `ToId` class implementing `Function<F, T>`

Comment: The only downsides are that this is a longer and maybe slower code.